# Can't add a printer shared on windows 7 on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, printing, samba

Running system-config-printer and  adding a printer shared on windows 7, I can browse the printer shares, it asks me the user an password (no need on windows so I type anything), then I select the printer, buy when y try to set the username and password so it doesn't ask me and click Verify it says  `The printer share is not accessible` and throws the following

```
File "/usr/share/system-config-printer/newprinter.py", line 2861, in on_btnSMBVerify_clicked
os.O_RDWR, 0o777)
smbc.ExistsError: (17, 'El archivo ya existe')
```

It worked before with Ubuntu 16.04, can't find the way to add a windows printer on 18.04.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that the access control list of the smb printer needs to be adjusted on the windows machine. I am not a windows person but on Windows servers there is a utility called icacls or similar that does this kind of stuff.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, finally I made it work by setting a password on the windows user and setting the username and password on the config dialog on ubuntu, it still says "The printer share is not accessible" but it works anyway.